# Springs and struts or autosizing

Tags: xcode, storyboard, struts, autolayout, autosize

-RE-EDIT-

An edit was just approved on this post as it "fixed grammer[sic] and clarified the question".

In actuality, it made both worse so I've changed it back.

-EDIT-

I have a storyboard layout like this:

[image]

If I use auto layout, I get this in the simulator:

[image]

If I switch it off, and use this setting:

[image]

I get this:

[image]

Which is as close to the desired layout as I could manage with trial and error.

Anyone offer any tips on how how set it so it matches the storyboard?

Comment: Struts and springs are Autoresizing masks, Auto-Layout is totally different.  Which are you using?

Comment: OK, well I'm even more puzzled now. Under `File Inspector` there is a checkbox, `Use Autolayout`. If not selected, what I referred to as the "springs and struts" (shown in the third image above) becomes available. If `Use Autolayout` is selected, the option to set these "springs and struts" is unavailable. Apologies if they're called something else. That's how I've always referred to them.